# Is there a tool like omnipeek? Which tool can be used to capture wlan packets?

Tags: wireless, networking, software-recommendation

I want to find a tool like omnipeek on my ubuntu precise, but didn't find.

Which tools can be used to capture WLAN packets on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark is a relatively popular tool, and works on a few flavors of Linux, as well as Mac and Windows

http://www.wireshark.org/

Looks like it's also in the repos

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, I launch wireshark and encounter "Couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap in child process: permission denied", what is wrong?

Comment: Is wireshark like omnipeek?

Comment: @OliveTwist I'm not familiar with omnipeek, but Wireshark does packet capture

Comment: @VictorS try running with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have and use Omnipeek... Use wireshark/dumpcap or even tcpdump on your Linux system to capture the packets to a PCAPNG format to be analysed in Omnipeek.